# Bootstrap datepicker: Select entire week and put week interval in input field

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I am currently using bootstrap-datepicker (https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker), but want to be able to select entire weeks in the calendar (Monday to Sunday), as well as display the week interval in the input field that I am selecting from. 
The default interval in the input field should be the week that you are currently in.

I have seen a somewhat similar method using jQuery UI to display the interval on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MqD2n/).

```
C
```

I have tried editing this code to work for bootstrap-datepicker, without any luck.

Any idea how I can implement this for bootstrap-datepicker? :
[image: The steps are outlined in this image]

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to use Bootstrap? The HTML5 tag `<input type="week">` on the default browser datepicker should do this for you.

Comment: Yes, it is already implemented throughout the solution. Thank you for your comment though!

Comment: As awesome as it `<input type="week">` is, it does not work in Firefox (tested with v40.0.3).

Answer (score 43):

I have used Bootstrap datetime picker in my project ran into same problem like yours When trying to select the weeks.

Got the below Solution on my own you can try it.

**Required Files :**

1. Bootstrap.css
2. Bootstrapdatetime picker css(You can use only datepicker instead of datetime)
3. jquery.js
4. Bootstrap.js
5. moment.js
6. Bootstrap Date time Picker js(Again you can use only datepicker instead of datetime)

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <div class="input-group" id="DateDemo">
              <input type='text' id='weeklyDatePicker' placeholder="Select Week" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS :** Used the moment.js for calculating the start and end of the week.

```
//Initialize the datePicker(I have taken format as mm-dd-yyyy, you can have your own)
$("#weeklyDatePicker").datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
});

//Get the value of Start and End of Week
$('#weeklyDatePicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
    value = $("#weeklyDatePicker").val();
    firstDate = moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(0).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
    lastDate =  moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(6).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
    $("#weeklyDatePicker").val(firstDate + "   -   " + lastDate);
});
```

**CSS :**

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget tr:hover {
    background-color: #808080;
}
```

Link to Working Code in JSFiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/9usq3enn/

Comment: Hi, this is awesome and very close, but how do I get the date value, i.e. how to get and `POST the Monday date` of the selected week back to server

Comment: This works great for me but I did one modification for the default value, when using this in a form that was already completed (so editing the values) the date was truncating the field.$("#weeklyDatePicker").datetimepicker({
      format: 'MM-DD-YYYY - MM-DD-YYYY'
  });

Comment: Here is my fiddle based on all the answers. Might help someone: https://jsfiddle.net/prtk/znbx32j1/1/

Answer (score 11):

I have optimized the above mentioned examples.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">    
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
           <div class="input-group" id="DateDemo">
               <input type='text' id='weeklyDatePicker' placeholder="Select Week" />
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    moment.locale('en', {
      week: { dow: 1 } // Monday is the first day of the week
    });

  //Initialize the datePicker(I have taken format as mm-dd-yyyy, you can     //have your owh)
  $("#weeklyDatePicker").datetimepicker({
      format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
  });

   //Get the value of Start and End of Week
  $('#weeklyDatePicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
      var value = $("#weeklyDatePicker").val();
      var firstDate = moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(0).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
      var lastDate =  moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(6).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
      $("#weeklyDatePicker").val(firstDate + " - " + lastDate);
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .datepicker-days table tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Check the link for demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/IamMHussain/ozdrdbqf/1/

Comment: This should be submitted as an edit to the relevant answer - though you'll need a little more [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to be able to propose it.

Comment: Is there anyway to use this solution with bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 3):

I am currently working on a project with the same requirement. Don't know where I found it, but this fiddle on http://codepen.io/chanduvkm/pen/yeXKGW addresses almost the same issue in a slightly different way, but using the bootstrap-datepicker library you are currently using. The default value could be easily added. However, the CSS of the active week fails when the option 'weekStart: 1' is set, which is what I actually need (ISO-8601 week starts on Monday).

```
    var startDate,
    endDate;

  $('#weekpicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format :'mm/dd/yyyy',
    forceParse :false
}).on("changeDate", function(e) {
    //console.log(e.date);
    var date = e.date;
    startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
    endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay()+6);
    //$('#weekpicker').datepicker("setDate", startDate);
    $('#weekpicker').datepicker('update', startDate);
    $('#weekpicker').val((startDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + startDate.getDate() + '/' +  startDate.getFullYear() + ' - ' + (endDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + endDate.getDate() + '/' +  endDate.getFullYear());
});
```

In response to the previous answer by prakash, I forked the fiddle to start on Monday: https://jsfiddle.net/skfw0k53/ by adding the following:

```
    moment.locale('en', {
  week: { dow: 1 } // Monday is the first day of the week
});
```

So, basically two different libs to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try it.

**Required file:**

jquery-1.11.3.js
bootstrap-datepicker.min.js
bootstrap-datepicker.css
bootstrap.min.css

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class='col-md-3'>
    Week Start <select id="cweek">
      <option value='0'> 0 </option>
      <option value='1'> 1 </option>
      <option value='2'> 2 </option>
      <option value='3'> 3 </option>
      <option value='4'> 4 </option>
      <option value='5'> 5 </option>
      <option value='6'> 6 </option>
      <option value='7'> 7 </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-3'>
    Copy <select name='cweek_number' id='cweek_number'>
      <option value='1'> 1 Week </option>
      <option value='2'> 2 Week </option>
      <option value='3'> 3 Week </option>
      <option value='4'> 4 Week </option>
    </select> from
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">


      <div class="from_cal"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">



      <div class="to_cal"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
var weekOfStart = 0;
      var startDate;
      var endDate;
      var toCal_startDate;
      var toCal_endDate;
      var setNumberOfWeek = 1;

      var from_cal = '.from_cal';
      var to_cal = '.to_cal';

      var obj =   $(from_cal).datepicker({
                  weekStart:weekOfStart,
                  maxViewMode: 0,
                  onSelect: function (date) {

                  },
                  beforeShowDay: function(date)
                  {
                    var cssClass = '';
                      if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                          cssClass = 'oui-state-hover';
                      return [true, cssClass];
                  }
              //    startDate: new Date()
        });


      $(from_cal).on('changeDate', function(evt) {
          var date = evt.date;
          var dayAdjustment = date.getDay() - weekOfStart;
          if (dayAdjustment < 0) {
              dayAdjustment += 7;
          }
          if(setNumberOfWeek > 1)
          {
            weekLast = 7*(setNumberOfWeek-1);
          }
          else {
            weekLast = 0;
          }
          startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - dayAdjustment);
          endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - dayAdjustment + (6+weekLast));

          // console.log(startDate);
          // console.log(endDate);

          $(this).find('.active').closest('tr').addClass('oui-selected');
          if(setNumberOfWeek > 1)
          {
            $(this).find('.active').closest('tr').nextAll().slice(0, (setNumberOfWeek-1)).addClass('oui-selected');
          }
      });

        $(from_cal).on('mousemove', '.table-condensed tr', function () {
            $(this).find('td').addClass('oui-state-hover');
            if(setNumberOfWeek > 1)
            {

            $(this).nextAll().slice(0, (setNumberOfWeek-1)).find('td').addClass('oui-state-hover');
            }

        });
        $(from_cal).on('mouseleave', '.table-condensed tr', function () {

              $(this).find('td').removeClass('oui-state-hover');

              $(this).nextAll().find('td').removeClass('oui-state-hover');

        });


        $(from_cal).find('td').on('click', function(){

          console.log('ok');
        });

    obj.datepicker();


// To date Calendar  code

        var toCalObj =   $(to_cal).datepicker({
                      weekStart:weekOfStart,
                      maxViewMode: 0,
                  //    startDate: new Date()
        });
        toCalObj.datepicker();
        $(to_cal).on('mousemove', '.table-condensed tr', function () {
            $(this).find('td').addClass('kui-state-hover');
            if(setNumberOfWeek > 1)
            {

            $(this).nextAll().slice(0, (setNumberOfWeek-1)).find('td').addClass('kui-state-hover');
            }

        });
        $(to_cal).on('mouseleave', '.table-condensed tr', function () {

              $(this).find('td').removeClass('kui-state-hover');

              $(this).nextAll().find('td').removeClass('kui-state-hover');

        });

        $(to_cal).on('changeDate', function(evt) {

            var date = evt.date;
            var dayAdjustment = date.getDay() - weekOfStart;
            if (dayAdjustment < 0) {
                dayAdjustment += 7;
            }
            if(setNumberOfWeek > 1)
            {
              weekLast = 7*(setNumberOfWeek-1);
            }
            else {
              weekLast = 0;
            }
            toCal_startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - dayAdjustment);
            toCal_endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - dayAdjustment + (6+weekLast));

            console.log(toCal_startDate);
            console.log(toCal_endDate);

            $(this).find('.active').closest('tr').addClass('oui-selected');
            if(setNumberOfWeek > 1)
            {
              $(this).find('.active').closest('tr').nextAll().slice(0, (setNumberOfWeek-1)).addClass('oui-selected');
            }

          //  console.log(date.getDay());
        });


//comman code

      $('#cweek').change(function()
    {
      weekOfStart =  $('#cweek').val();
      obj.datepicker('destroy');
      toCalObj.datepicker('destroy');
      obj.datepicker({weekStart:$('#cweek').val(),maxViewMode:0}).datepicker('update');
      toCalObj.datepicker({weekStart:$('#cweek').val(),maxViewMode:0}).datepicker('update');
    });

    $('#cweek_number').change(function()
    {
      setNumberOfWeek = $('#cweek_number').val();
      obj.datepicker('destroy');
      toCalObj.datepicker('destroy');
      obj.datepicker({weekStart:$('#cweek').val(),maxViewMode:0}).datepicker('update');
      toCalObj.datepicker({weekStart:$('#cweek').val(),maxViewMode:0}).datepicker('update');

    });


    $('.table-condensed').addClass('table');
```

**Screen Shot**

[image]

JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/shivamanhar/ddphp8jx/9/

Answer (score 0):

If someone uses daterangepicker instead
please follow the extension to make weeks selected

```
//moment.locale('ru') //depending on locale you can move start of week

set_picker_start_end = (picker, when) => {
  
  let m = (when == 'now') ? moment() : moment(when) //moment

  let week_start  = m.startOf('isoweek')
  let week_end    = m.clone().endOf('isoweek')
  
  picker.setStartDate(week_start);
  picker.setEndDate(week_end);
}

$("#week-dp").daterangepicker({
  // "showDropdowns": true,
  "showISOWeekNumbers": true,
  "autoApply": true,
  "showCustomRangeLabel": false,
  // "startDate": '', //not work because of one calendar. will be set further
  // "endDate": '', //not work because of one calendar. will be set further
  "drops": "down",
  "singleDatePicker" : true, //to make one click and one calendar
  "locale": {
    "format": "W [week of] GGGG",
    "weekLabel": "#",
  },
});

set_picker_start_end($("#week-dp").data('daterangepicker'), 'now') //set current week selected

$("#week-dp").on('show.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {

  let active_cell = picker.container[0].querySelector('td.start-date')
  active_cell.parentElement.classList.add('active') //tr goes active
});

$("#week-dp").on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {

    set_picker_start_end(picker, picker.startDate)
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dj_floyd/f2hoygdw/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ autoclose: true,format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',forceParse :false }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
  var value = $("#datepicker").val();
  var firstDate = moment(value, "YYYY-MM-DD").day(0).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  var lastDate =  moment(value, "YYYY-MM-DD").day(6).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  $("#datepicker").val(firstDate + " / " + lastDate);
});
```

```css
.datepicker .datepicker-days .table-condensed tr:hover {
  background-color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://gotoastro.local.com/assets/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" value="">
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://gotoastro.com/front-assets/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -4):

A very quick solution:
1. Modify JS file: bootstrap-datepicker.js
2. Modify CSS file: bootstrap-datepicker3.css
3. Modify your code.

```js
        //Modifications on bootstrap-datepicker.js
        //-----
        if (!target.hasClass('disabled')){
                // Clicked on a day
                if (target.hasClass('day')){
                        day = parseInt(target.text(), 10) || 1;
                        year = this.viewDate.getUTCFullYear();
                        month = this.viewDate.getUTCMonth();
                        //HF[+][i]201612151500
                        datepickerPlugin.actualWeek = $(target[0].parentNode).find('.cw').text();
                        //HF[+][f]201612151500
                        // From last month
                        if (target.hasClass('old')){
                                if (month === 0) {
                                        month = 11;
                                        year = year - 1;
                                        monthChanged = true;
                                        yearChanged = true;
                                } else {
                                        month = month - 1;
                                        monthChanged = true;
                                }
                        }
        //-----
        //HF[-][i]201612151500
        //   validParts: /dd?|DD?|mm?|MM?|yy(?:yy)?/g,
        //HF[-][f]201612151500
        //HF[+][i]201612151500
        validParts: /ww?|dd?|DD?|mm?|MM?|yy(?:yy)?/g,
        //HF[+][f]201612151500
        nonpunctuation: /[^ -\/:-@\u5e74\u6708\u65e5\[-`{-~\t\n\r]+/g,
        parseFormat: function(format){
                if (typeof format.toValue === 'function' && typeof format.toDisplay === 'function')
                        return format;
                // IE treats \0 as a string end in inputs (truncating the value),
                // so it's a bad format delimiter, anyway
                var separators = format.replace(this.validParts, '\0').split('\0'),
                        parts = format.match(this.validParts);
                if (!separators || !separators.length || !parts || parts.length === 0){
                        throw new Error("Invalid date format.");
                }
                return {separators: separators, parts: parts};
        },
        //-----
        formatDate: function(date, format, language){
                if (!date)
                        return '';
                if (typeof format === 'string')
                        format = DPGlobal.parseFormat(format);
                if (format.toDisplay)
                        return format.toDisplay(date, format, language);
                var val = {
                        //HF[+][i]201612151500
                        ww: 'Semana ' + datepickerPlugin.actualWeek.toString(),
                        //HF[+][f]201612151500
                        d: date.getUTCDate(),
                        D: dates[language].daysShort[date.getUTCDay()],
                        DD: dates[language].days[date.getUTCDay()],
                        m: date.getUTCMonth() + 1,
                        M: dates[language].monthsShort[date.getUTCMonth()],
                        MM: dates[language].months[date.getUTCMonth()],
                        yy: date.getUTCFullYear().toString().substring(2),
                        yyyy: date.getUTCFullYear()
                };
                val.dd = (val.d < 10 ? '0' : '') + val.d;
                val.mm = (val.m < 10 ? '0' : '') + val.m;
                date = [];
                var seps = $.extend([], format.separators);
                for (var i=0, cnt = format.parts.length; i <= cnt; i++){
                        if (seps.length)
                                date.push(seps.shift());
                        date.push(val[format.parts[i]]);
                }
                return date.join('');
        },
        //-----
```

```css
        .datepicker tbody tr:hover {
         background-color: #eee;
        }
        .datepicker tbody tr:hover td,
        .datepicker tbody tr td.active {
         border-radius: 0;
        }
        .datepicker tbody tr:hover td:last-child,
        .datepicker tbody tr td.active:last-child {
         border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
        }
        .datepicker tbody tr:hover td:first-child,
        .datepicker tbody tr  td.active:nth-child(2) {
         border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
        }
```

```html
        <!--RefLinks-->
        <link href="~/libraries/bootstrap-datepicker-1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="~/libraries/bootstrap-datepicker-1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
 
        <!--OnBody-->
        <input id="datepicker2" class="datepicker4" style="width: 300px;" type="text">

        <!--OnScriptSection-->
        $(function ()
        {
            var $weekPicker = $("#datepicker2");
            $weekPicker.datepicker
                (
                    {
                        autoclose: true,
                        format: 'ww', //'dd-M-yyyy',
                        calendarWeeks: true,
                        //maxViewMode: 0,
                        weekStart: 1
                    }
                )
```

Comment: Modifying vendor files is a very bad practice.  Not recommending this.