# fetch the week number bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

please help me, i have searched on how to get the week number and range. I have found the following sources..[stackoverflow.com/questions/30230615/fetch-week-number-and-week-start-end-date-using-bootstrap-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230615/fetch-week-number-and-week-start-end-date-using-bootstrap-datepicker) and
[Bootstrap datepicker: Select entire week and put week interval in input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713964/bootstrap-datepicker-select-entire-week-and-put-week-interval-in-input-field/34129546#34129546)

I tried to play with the codes so that I could select the entire week and put week interval in input field and show the week number. But it is not working for me, can someone help me solve my problem? Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Here are the script tags I used.

```
 <!--jquery-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--bootstrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--datepicker-->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<!--moment-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
```

Here is my html code.

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datepicker2'>
     <input type='text' id='datepicker' class="form-control"  />
     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
     <div id="output"></div>
```

And here is my javascript..

```
                $('#datepicker2').on('dp.change', function (e) {
                var kk = $('#datepicker2').val();
                var value = $('#datepicker2').val();

                var firstDate = moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(0).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
                var lastDate =  moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(6).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
                $('#datepicker2').val(firstDate + " - " + lastDate);


                $("#output").html(
                "Week Number: " + moment(kk, "DD/MM/YYYY").week() + " of " + 
                moment(kk, "DD/MM/YYYY").weeksInYear()
                );

            });
```

Comment: 1st of all, why are you using bootstrap js of 2 versions(3.3.6 & 3.2.0) and 2ndly using datepicker js & css after bootstrap js & css. NOTE - CSS should be includeed in head of html and js at the end of body tag.

Comment: @user294 thank you for answering, is it really a must to put the js at the end of the body tag?

Comment: Yes..it is necessary to make sure your HTML is loaded before your js files start loading. Further you can refer this - https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: i have already did the necessary edits on my code but still my code above is not working. it only shows like a normal datepicker. I wanted actually to output the week number and the week interval. @user2947